Ошибка "System.InvalidOperationException: "Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть."

Необходимо сделать метод, который заполняет DataSet таблицами из заранее известной базы данных MSSQL.
Количество таблиц может разниться, поэтому используется запрос SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
Выводит ошибку из заголовка при попытке выполнить метод adapter.Fill(ds, reader.GetString(0)); внутри цикла while.
    public static void RefreshDS()
    {
        ds.Reset();
        OpenConnection();
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"select * from {reader.GetString(0)}", conn);
                adapter.Fill(ds, reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader.HasRows && !reader.IsClosed)
                reader.Close();
            CloseConnection();
        }
    }

Если удалить метод adapter.Fill(ds, reader.GetString(0));, ошибка выводиться не будет, и цикл будет продолжаться, но тогда теряется весь смысл метода RefreshDS
Буду благодарен за помощь

Либо включите MARS, либо сперва сохраните имена таблиц в коллекцию, а затем проходите циклом по этой коллекции, вызывая адаптер.

Да, способ сохранения названий таблиц в коллекцию помог.
Включение MARS тоже помогло, теперь метод работает так, как я планировал.
Спасибо!)

Самое простое, сделать здесь последовательно
public static void RefreshDS()
{
    ds.Reset();
    OpenConnection();
    try
    {
        List<string> tables = new();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'", conn))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tables.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        foreach (string table in tables)
        {
            using SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {table}", conn);
            adapter.Fill(ds, table);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }
}

В противном случае следует использовать разные подключения для ридера и адаптера. Ну или включить MARS.

Совсем не интуитивно-понятная особенность работы с подключением.
Я даже не знаю, что будет более профитнее для оптимизации процесса - сначала заносить значения в коллекцию, или работать с двумя подключениями
Спасибо за помощь, метод работает)

@privet_so_dna если у вас меньше 1000 таблиц, вряд-ли вы увидите разницу по производительности или памяти, какой бы способ вы не выбрали.
